# Geoserver has trouble translating date time to right UTC timezone

Tags: datetime, postgis, utc, geoserver

Geoserver has a problem while translating date time.

We have a column "effective_begin_time" defined as a "timestamp with
timezone" in postgres. It was specified this way hoping that all
date/time will be stored in UTC format. However when doing a WFS-T
insert using geoserver, we have it defined as:

2015-03-09T20:20:00 PDT

Geoserver inserts this value as 2015-03-09T20:20:00Z into the DB
  ignoring the 'PDT' timezone. I was expecting the date be stored as
  2015-03-10 03:20:00+00

I have turned on the debug and found that Geoserver inserts the value as
2015-03-09T20:20:00Z, ignoring the PDT. Geoserver is deployed as a WAR within Tomcat and
have set the user.timezone=GMT as documented. I am not sure why this is
happening. I verified that while executing the insert from psql, the
value is stored in the right UTC form. Can someone tell me what needs to
be done to ensure that the date gets inserted in the UTC form correctly?

Comment: Please do not [cross post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/138216/geoserver-has-trouble-translating-date-time-to-right-utc-timezone)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has already been asked/answered on gis.stackexchange

Comment: the GIS stack exhange post is no longer active. can we get the answer here ?